# Navigation toggler is not working in browser but working in codeply

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have tried to include navigation bar with toggler. The code is working fine in codeply but not in browser. The toggler button (hamburger button) is appearing when in mobile but not showing the lists. Below is my code.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Practice</title>  
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
   rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384- 
   1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
 </head>
 <body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">WonderWeb</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs- 
     target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" 
     aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
     <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Products</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Payment</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </nav>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Many of Bootstrap 5 components require the use of JavaScript to function.
You forgot to include special links from [Bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/) and You had wrong id in here

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
```

---

It should be like this =>

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
```

Now it's works perfectly ;-) Best regards!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover"
    />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Solved ;-) </title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">WonderWeb</a>
        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02"
          aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Products</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Payment</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```